Using intersection observer and scroll top to determine div percentage when scrolling up
I'm working on creating a special fade-out animation that only happens when a user is scrolling up through a div (it has a separate animation when scrolling down that I don't want to alter and it happens at a different time so I can't just toggle classes).
I have the animation working as far as CSS goes, but I've stripped down the code to get the trigger working as that's my last hurdle. I can trigger when I enter the middle div section (as seen in the console log) but the hiccup seems to be where I determine scroll direction.
As you can see in the example, if you scroll back up into the div the console log does appear. However, when I call the handleScroll function and try to log the scroll direction it doesn't show anything. That's my last remaining step is just determining scroll direction upon div entry and then if the user is indeed scrolling up just check to see if they're 50% through the div.
Why aren't these triggers occurring?


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const section = document.querySelector('.mountain-sect');

  // Function to handle intersection changes
  function handleIntersection(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        // Add scroll listener when entering the div
        console.log('in section ');
        section.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      } else {
        // Remove scroll listener when leaving the div
        section.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      }
    });
  }

  // Function to handle scroll event
function handleScroll(event) {
    console.log('scrolling');
  const target = event.target;
  const scrollTop = target.scrollTop;
  const scrollDirection = scrollTop > previousScrollTop ? 'down' : 'up';
  const scrollHeight = target.scrollHeight;
  const clientHeight = target.clientHeight;
  const scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)) * 100;
  console.log(scrollDirection);

  if (scrollDirection === 'up' && scrollPercentage < 50) {
    window.alert('You are more than 50% through the div while scrolling up.');
  }

  previousScrollTop = scrollTop;
}


  // Create an Intersection Observer instance
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

  // Observe the target element
  observer.observe(section);
});
<div class="container">
<div style="position: relative;"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></div>
<div class="mountain-sect" style="position: relative;"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></div>
<div style="position: relative;"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></div>
</div>




To achieve this, you need to detect the scroll direction and the position of the scroll relative to the div. Here's a basic example of how you can achieve this using JavaScript:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Scroll Fade-out Animation</title>
<style>
  body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .container {
    height: 2000px; /* Just for demonstration */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
  }

  .content {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  }

  .fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="content" id="content">
    Scroll inside this div...
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const content = document.getElementById('content');

  let lastScrollTop = 0;

  container.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    const scrollTop = container.scrollTop;

    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
      // Scrolling down
      content.classList.remove('fade-out');
    } else {
      // Scrolling up
      content.classList.add('fade-out');
    }

    lastScrollTop = scrollTop <= 0 ? 0 : scrollTop; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>


That just adds a listener to the container which doesn't do anything as far as looking at scroll within the container. That's why I've used intersection observer to pinpoint entry into the container (which I've already got working in my example). The issue now is that I need to detect scroll direction and percentage of div visibility
